# PHP exec enabled?

Tags: php, exec

exec() appears to be enabled on the server (function_exists('exec') returns true, and command is not listed in 'disable_functions' variable) yet we get

Warning:  exec() has been disabled for security reasons in ...

Any clues on how to detect this before calling?

EDIT:

It was suhosin blacklist and can be checked with following code

if (extension_loaded('suhosin')) {
    $suhosin = @ini_get("suhosin.executor.func.blacklist");
   ...

Comment: Thanks for the update. Could you post the solution as an answer, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was suhosin blacklist and can be checked with following code

if (extension_loaded('suhosin')) { $suhosin = @ini_get("suhosin.executor.func.blacklist"); ..

Answer (score 3):

as written in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php) for the safe mode:
`You can only execute executables within the safe_mode_exec_dir.`

Answer (score 0):

I answered this in another question page. Its not before the call, but that shouldn't matter.
 Here is my answer ;)

```
// This will check if the function actually works.('permissions, rights, ect ..')

if(@exec('echo EXEC') == 'EXEC'){
    echo 'exec works';
}
```